# Wrapping head around PDF/CDF of min(Uniforms) conditioned on X=1/x!(e-1), pdf=1-cdf?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

From Casella and Berger: I've run into an interesting property while doing exercises. The property being: 
$$f_Z(z) = 1-F_Z(z)$$
Would like to know if it is a result of a mistake or an actual property of a special set-up, and if so, if there are applications for this (visualizations would be amazing!).

**The process of running into this property is as follows:**

Suppose $U_1,...,U_X$ are a sample of uniform random variables. Let $Z\sim min(U_1,...,U_X)$. Finally X itself is a discrete random variable defined as: 
$$P(X=x)=\frac{1}{x!(e-1)}, \ \ x=1,2,3,...$$
Find the distribution of Z. Assuming they mean pdf, I decided to interpret $Z=min(U_1,...,U_X)=U_{(1)}$, as an order statistic problem.

Thus: 
$$P(U_{(1)}=z|X=x)=\frac{x!}{0!(x-1)!}f_U(z)[F_U(z)]^0[1-F_U(Z)]^{X-1}$$
By the pdf of any order statistic given continuous random samples.
Simplifying: 
$$P(U_{(1)}=z|X=x)=x(1-z)^{x-1}$$
By the law of total probability: 
$$P(U_{(1)}=z)= \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}P(U_{(1)}=z|X=x)P(X=x)$$
$$= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{x(1-z)^{x-1}}{x!(e-1)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{e-1}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{(1-z)^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}$$
$$P(U_{(1)}=z)=P(Z=z)=\frac{e^{1-z}-1}{e-1}, 0<z<1$$

Hoping there aren't any stupid mistakes here. Now the conundrum begins when we derive $P(Z>z)$

$$P(Z>z)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty P(Z>z|X=x)P(X=x)$$
$$=\sum_{x=1}^\infty P(U_1>z,...,U_X>z|X=x)P(X=x)$$
By i.i.d uniform samples:
$$=\frac{1}{e-1}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{(1-z)^x}{x!}$$
$$P(Z>z)=1-F_Z(z)=\frac{e^{1-z}-1}{e-1}=f_Z(z), \ \  0<z<1$$

They have the same distribution. Curious to whether there is a mistake anywhere or whether this is some special case, if so, are there any useful applications/visualizations for this?

Comment: This may not answer your question but the only CDF f on $(0,\infty)$ such that $1-F(z)=f(z)$ is the exponential density $f(z)= \lambda e^{-\lambda z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a mistake in your calculation. The proof is correct up to the point of identifying $f_Z(z) = P(U_{(1)}=z)$; this should be

\begin{align*}
f_Z(z) &= 
\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}P(U_{(1)}=z|X=x)P(X=x)\\
&= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{x(1-z)^{x-1}}{x!(e-1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{e-1}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{(1-z)^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}\\
& = \frac{e^{1-z}}{e-1}
\end{align*}

I then agree with your derivation that leads to
$$1 - F_Z(z) = \frac{e - e^{1-z}}{e -1},$$
which means the correct identity is in fact
$$ 1 - F_Z(z) = \frac{e}{e-1} - f_Z(z),$$
or more simply
$$f_Z(z) = \frac1{1-e} + F_Z(z).$$

Comment: Ah i see the error! Substituting y = x - 1 into the first proof should yield the correct distribution. Thank you. I had mistakenly taken the sum as an exponential missing the 1 that comes out of (x-1)=0 - leading to *e - 1*.

Comment: Exactly; sorry, I meant to explain that in the post but forgot.